# How do you Pipe hex data directly to bc and converting it to binary - cleanly?

Tags: bash, hex, hexdump, bc

Hex (character) to binary conversion is useful, especially when you want to look at a few bits mushed inside some hex string.

It is for this reason that I would like to pipe some hex data to bc (the Unix program known as 'basic calculator') and convert it to binary characters (1s and 0s).

Generally I would like to cat a file of hex data (lines hex data in a file) and pipe it to bc and have bc convert it to binary. Alternatively I could convert a binary file to hex with xxd and pipe that to bc.

There are ways to do this, but given that bc needs a few directives, all the methods seem a bit convoluted. How can this be done simply, without a bash script with some for loop?

Comment: What's the question here exactly?

Comment: I have rewritten the question. I am using bc to convert Hex to Binary. I am seeking a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks - Looks okay, but returned > character , I think there is a syntax error in your solution. Good start though.

Comment: The result yielded many:

0
0
(standard_in) 21788: parse error
(standard_in) 21789: parse error
(standard_in) 21790: parse error
(standard_in) 21791: parse error

Comment: You are right ... I missed the "-u" ... Thanks! Good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

```
{ echo "obase=2; ibase=16"; xxd -c 32 -u -p file.bin; } | bc
```

It just feeds both the settings and the streamed file contents to `bc` with a brace list. The `-u` flag to `xxd` makes it output upper case hex letters.

Answer (score 0):

Since StackOverflow, encourages answering your own question, this is my solution:

```
xxd -c 32 -p file.bin | awk '{print toupper($0)}' | tr '\n' ' ' |  { read line; for i in $line; do echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $i" | bc ; done }
```

I do not like my solution because it seems convoluted. I would like to devise a way to pipe the output of xxd to bc, without the for loop, and without using tr (which I could have used to uppercase as well). Anyway, it works but I think it can be done better.

Comment: This would seem to be an integral part of the question since the question, on its own, is still rather lacking an actual full question.

Comment: Ideally I would like to craft the most optimal question. This answer can live it its state, I am sure a better answer will appear.